# jquery modal not showing with asp.net master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am attempting to display a jquery modal popup using the following code:

```
 protected void gvGroupSummary_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
                {
                    int code = Convert.ToInt32(gvGroupSummary.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());
                    IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                 where i.Field<int>("GroupID").Equals(code)
                                                 select i;
                    DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
                    DetailsView1.DataSource = detailTable;
                    DetailsView1.DataBind();
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
                    sb.Append("$('#detailModal').modal('show');");
                    sb.Append(@"</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "DetailModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.Error.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The HTML is:

```
 <!-- Detail Modal Starts here-->
    <div id="detailModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Detailed View</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" FieldHeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FieldHeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" FieldHeaderStyle-BackColor="LavenderBlush" FieldHeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Groove" AutoGenerateRows="False">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupID" HeaderText="Group ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupCode" HeaderText="Group Code" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" HeaderText="Group Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupType" HeaderText="Group Type" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="PreviousEstimateCosts" HeaderText="Previous Estimate Costs" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalEstimates" HeaderText="Total Estimate Costs" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="PreviousEstimateVariance" HeaderText="Previous Estimate Variance" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalActuals" HeaderText="Total Actual Costs" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="EstimateActualVariance" HeaderText="Estimate Actual Variance" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="EstimateActualVariancePct" HeaderText="Estimate Actual Variance PCT" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="FinancialYear" HeaderText="Financial Year" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="HasComments" HeaderText="Comments" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvGroupSummary" EventName="RowCommand" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Detail Modal Ends here -->
```

I have tested the code without the Master Page and it works. When I use a Master Page and click on the "detail" button, the main page darkens but the popup does not appear. After researching the issue, it appears the problem is with this portion, but I am not sure how to alter it:

```
 sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
                    sb.Append("$('#detailModal').modal('show');");
                    sb.Append(@"</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "DetailModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any script error in browser's console?

Comment: In Chrome, under console, no errors appear when I click on the "detail" button. What does appear under 'Elements' is the following line: <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>

Answer (score -1):

Try this
VB.NET Version

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("$(document).ready(function() {$('#Your_Modal').modal();});")
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, [GetType](), "none", sb.ToString, True)
```